# Can you recommend effective ways to secure the developers within the team breaking the business-logic by mistake?

Tags: .net, programming-languages, project-management, communication

How do you secure the developers in your development team from breaking the business logic of the application - like by skipping some steps or forgetting an exceptional case etc.-?

What kind of preventions do you implement in order to decrease this risk in the live product? Do you give detailed trainings on business logic to new team members, do you use specific unit and integration tests, do you just rely on code that has the self-protection capability with some logical checks, by keeping a GOD like member in the company who knows everything?..

I think it is normal that some guys in a team have extraordinary knowledge on both DB and business logic. But I have a feeling there should be a kind of good way so that the developers are not too much dependent on such guys to be able to produce a good and error-less software. There should be a balance but how do you achieve such a balance?

Answer (score 3):

Code reviews are the primary way we enforce things like this. Almost none of our code gets checked in unless it's been reviewed first. I would also suggest using Code Analysis and have as many rules turned on as makes sense for you.

We also have weekly developer team meetings to discuss various ways of approaching software problems, and techniques we've developed etc. We might discuss WCF, Linq, SQL Server during these meetings. The idea is to keep the team up to date with ways we're solving problems.

Comment: How do you apply it? How many times in a sprint lets say. Or you do it spontaneously? Any guideline you have?

Comment: @burak - we have no formal times for doing code reviews. We simply have a policy where it must be done before code is checked into our main branch. And we have TFS enforce this.

Answer (score 2):

Implement the Domain Logic in a **separate project/library** and cover that library by **unit tests**.

Answer (score 1):

Get the devs to collaborate with analysts and testers to write scenarios which cover how a user will use their code, and why it's valuable. I usually phrase scenarios as:

```
Given <a context>
When <an event happens>
Then <an outcome occurs>.
```

They should be looking to discover the things they don't know about or think about, but which the testers do.

I use a couple of questions to help me with this. I question the context:

```
Given <the context in which we start>, 
when <I do this with the system>,
then <this happens>.

Is there any other context in which the same event produces
a different outcome?
Have we covered all the similar combinations?
```

And I question the outcome:

```
Given <the context in which we start>
when <I do this with the system>
then <this happens>

If I were to make that happen using something different - 
a manual process, say - would that cover the outcome you're 
hoping to achieve?
```

These two questions help me define the behaviour of the system and discover things I hadn't thought about. I can use these to write automated acceptance tests or scenarios if I want to. The questions also help me to learn about my domain and pass knowledge on to other developers.

If you have problems getting hold of analysts / business representatives and / or testers with whom to discuss these problems, then that's why your devs have bugs!

Otherwise, please take a look at BDD (Behavior Driven Development), which will help you find out more about how to do this, automated tools to help you turn these conversations into tests, etc.